# How to switch Views in Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I needed to do some changes to .csproj file. So, I switched to `Folder View` in the Solution Explorer. Now, I want to switch back to the default view (the one with the drop-down list containing properties and methods). But Visual Studio 2019 (v16.7.7) doesn't allow me to do that. Any workarounds?
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Double click the .sln file from the Folder View can allow you to switch to the default solution view.

Comment: How about reload the project, or open the .csproj file from File Explorer. I could switch back to the default view by doing either of the two.